# How to create standalone program by static linking in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, mysql, dll, static, static-libraries

I want to run my program standalone. It is simple connection to MySQL using libmysql.lib and requires libmysql.dll in order to run (have it in same folder). Now my question is, how could i compile in c::b so I can use my executable on other machine and will not require .dll? I heard about static libraries but I have no idea how it works, so would be really nice if someone could explain me the process.

P.S. I use GNU CC Compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <mysql.h>


using namespace std;


int main() {

MYSQL *connect;
MYSQL_RES *res_set;
MYSQL_ROW row;
connect = mysql_init(NULL);


connect = mysql_real_connect(connect, "HOST", "USER", "PASS", "Server", 3306, NULL, 0);

while( true ) {
    mysql_query(connect, "SELECT * FROM Server");

    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);

    while( row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set) ) {
        cout << row[0] << " " << row[1] << " " << row[2] << endl;
    }
    Sleep(2000);
}

mysql_close(connect);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code already, that someone could use as a starting point for helping you?

Comment: Here you go, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Project->Build Options->(Select project name)`. Then select the `Linker settings` and click on the `Add` button under `Link Libraries`, and select `libmysql.lib`. This should statically compile your program, AFAIK.

See the **Compiling MySQL Clients on Microsoft Windows** section in the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-building-clients.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I have actually already done that, as you wrote linked my library correctly. Then the case is, IF libmysql.dll not .lib, is in same folder as main.cpp or .exe file, the program will run correctly, otherwise give me an error that libmysql.dll is missing, thats what I'm trying to solve, so it runs even if libmysql.dll isnt there

Comment: Ah, right :) Hmm, try adding the `-static` & `-static-libgcc` flags to `Other linker options` text-box (on separate lines) in the same `Build Options` dialog.